# iPhone 13 photo and movie file suffixes have changed to strange characters, making them unusable

Tags: iphone, photos, filesystem

I move photos off my iPhone 13 (IOS 17.0) to my PC (Win 10) for further processing, using a cable.
There have never been any problems until recently, where photos (RAW format) and movies now have different suffixes: .DNG̀ (note the accent) instead of .DNG and .MOV̀ instead of .MOV. The photos are produced with Halide and movies with the native camera app.
I now can't open these files in other applications unless I first rename them to the normal suffixes.
(Also, the folders on the iPhone now have names like yyyymm_준 (note the strange character at the end) instead of the usual yyyymm.)
How does one get everything back to normal?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. However there is quite a lot of information missing in your question. Please edit to add the following. What model iPhone? What version of iOS? What camera app are you using to make DNG? What computer / OS / version? How did you move the photos from iPhone to computer? What has been updated recently? What new software have you installed recently? What applications are you using to process your photos?